# How to handle performance for 1000's of components on the screen in React Native?

Tags: ios, reactjs, performance, mobile, native

I am making an app where there is a 32x64 grid and when you click any square it will light up. I want the user to be able to drag their finger and it fills up all the squares the finger touches.

I am basically setting the state of my component to be an array of all of the squares and when a user touches the screen it switches the state to be a new array of squares (with one more filled) and renders the view.

With so many squares (components) on screen and with the re-rendering the performance is really bad on my phone. It is decent on my computer phone simulator, but could be better. I have tried adding a key to all of the squares in the array and I changed the square from a regular Component to a Pure Component, and although that did help performance it still could be a lot better.

After researching for a while, I decided I needed to reach out for guidance. I am trying to do this for IPhone, so do you think I should do the whole thing in swift if I want better performance or is there other ways to optimize the performance of a lot of components in React Native?

Answer (score 0):

Keys are required when returning multiple nodes.
PureComponent could help but you can use two more techniques.

1. Use simpler functional, stateless components.
2. Introduce `<Row />` component to divide updating complexity.